# Advice On Technologies Used For Online Payment Sites

Tags: onlinebanking

I would like to create a site along similar lines to justgiving.com, uk.virginmoneygiving.com etc.

In principle, it seems easy enough

- Organisation enters their bank details on my site
- Customer chooses organisation form a list
- Customer uses CC to make payment to organisation
- Money goes into central account (holding area)
- At a specified time, money gets transferred to organisation

I would like to give the customer the choice of storing their CC details on my site (more flexible for them) or not (more secure for them)

I was also thinking of making it an open app so that other businesses, through the use of an API, could use my banking system.

I'm more than aware of the cost involved in developing something like this (I'm not wet behind the ears)

Is there an easy middle ground to get up and running (use third parties) until I get the experience to develop my own system?

Could this be an off the shelf purchase or would I have to develop it bespoke (myslef or get an external company to do it)?

What sort of technologies would be involved?

Anything I've missed? I really don't know the terminology for what I want to do so my Googling has proved fuitless.

Who can point me in the right direction of good docs so I can learn the terminology/technology.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best and most secure option is to check out providers for this.
Their system can be integrated seamlessly in you site.

Do a google search and you'll find lots.

Take a look at paypal, [Ogone](http://www.ogone.be) etc.

Comment: Thanks for that. Ogone looks interesting and it's a good start for me.

Comment: I'd go for Ogone if I were you. You can even store your customer's data on their servers by making use of the **Alias manager**. So it's secure for your customers and easy for you!

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend [Quantiv](http://www.quantiv.com/Quantiv), they can provide a simple, modern payment back-end and they're quite affordable.